# Combining the elements of array and reformatting the output

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am having an input JSON which I would like to transform using Mule's dataweave 2.0.

Below is the input JSON.

```
[
   {
     "data1": {
                "role": "analyst",
                "name": "ABC"
     },
     "data2": {
                "role": "analyst",
                "name": "DEF"
     }
  },
  {
     "data1": {
                "role": "RM",
                "name": "PQRS"
     },
     "data2": {
                "role": "analyst",
                "name": "QWE"
     }
  }
]
```

We would like the output as below :

```
[
  {
     "role": "analyst",
     "name": "ABC"
  },
  {
     "role": "analyst",
     "name": "DEF"
  },
  {
     "role": "RM",
     "name": "PQRS"
  },
  {
     "role": "analyst",
     "name": "QWE"
  }
]
```

I have tried different options using map, pluck and flatten, but could not get the solution. Please help me with the transform function for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the order you can:

1) Go through the elements with `reduce` and for each object in the array, accumulate `data1` and `data2`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload reduce (item, acc = []) -> (acc << item.data1 << item.data2)
```

2) Using `map`, for each element in the array create an intermediate array containing `data1` and `data2` and then `flatten` that.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten (payload map (item) -> [item.data1, item.data2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the objects in response is important:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten (payload map (flatten $))
```

If the order is not important:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.data1 ++ payload.data2
```